# vbar in bokeh doesn't not support nonselection color and alpha?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Update the question:

How to select a certain species in barplot, nonselected bars will change color?
How to show text on top of each bar?

```
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

#color mapper to color data by species
mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors = ['setosa','versicolor', 'virginica'],\
                                 palette = ['green', 'blue', 'red'])


output_file("plots.html")

#group by species and plot barplot for count
species = flowers.groupby('species')

source = ColumnDataSource(species)

p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 400, title = 'Count by Species', \
           x_range = source.data['species'], tools = 'box_select')

p.vbar(x = 'species', top = 'petal_length_count', width = 0.8, source = source,\
       nonselection_fill_color = 'gray', nonselection_fill_alpha = 0.2,\
       color = {'field': 'species', 'transform': mapper})
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: please try to ask unrelated questions in separate SO posts.

---

Hit testing and selection was not implemented for `vbar` and `hbar` until recently. Using the recent `0.12.11` release, your code behaves as you are wanting:

[image]

Regarding labels for each bar, you want to use the `LabelSet` annotation, as [demonstrated in the User's Guide](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#labels) Something like:

```
labels = LabelSet(x='species', y='petal_count_length', text='some_column', 
                  x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=source)

p.add_layout(labels)
```

The linking question is too vague. I would suggest opening a new SO question with more information and description of what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works and solve my first two questions. I updated the code with your suggestion and ask a separate question about the linked graph here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579840/how-to-link-vbar-with-circle-plots-using-bokeh